# Flutter - Android * Generar función parametrizada de un inputdialog, que pueda ser llamada desde cualquier lugar

Tags: flutter, aplicación-movil

Flutter - android
en el envento onPressed de un ElevatedButton tengo el siguiente código:

```
                    showDialog(
                      barrierDismissible: false,
                      context: context,
                      builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
                        title: const Text('Correo electrónico'),
                        // content: const Text(''),
                        content: TextField(
                          
                        ),
                        actions: [
                          ElevatedButton(
                            child: const Text('Aceptar'),
                            onPressed: () {
                              Navigator.of(context).pop('ok');
                            },
                          ),
                          ElevatedButton(
                            child: const Text('Cancelar'),
                            onPressed: () {
                              Navigator.of(context).pop('cancel');
                            },
                          )
                        ],
                      )
                    )
```

y la idea que esté en un archivo separado y retorne el valor que ingresó el usuario...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si revisas las fuentes de `showDialog`, encontrarás que es un método global definido en uno de los archivos del framework, entonces podrías hacer algo similar.

Creas un archivo por ejemplo `my_dialog.dart`, donde defines tu método global, algo así:

```dart
Future<T?> showMyDialog<T>({
  required BuildContext context,
  required String title,
  required Widget content,
  bool barrierDismissible = true,
  Color? barrierColor,
}) {
  
  return showDialog(
                      barrierDismissible: barrierDismissible,
                      context: context,
                      builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
                        title: title,
                        content: content,
                        actions: [
                          ElevatedButton(
                            child: const Text('Aceptar'),
                            onPressed: () {
                              Navigator.of(context).pop(true);
                            },
                          ),
                          ElevatedButton(
                            child: const Text('Cancelar'),
                            onPressed: () {
                              Navigator.of(context).pop(false);
                            },
                          )
                        ],
                      )
                    );
}
```

Luego desde cualquier archivo puedes importar ese archivo y llamar al método que definiste:

```dart
 final result = (await showMyDialog(context: context, title: 'Titulo', content: TuWidgetDeContenido())) ?? false
```

También podrías parametrizar el texto del botón aceptar y cancelar, eso ya depende de ti.
En la respuesta, solo retorna `true` si presionó el botón positivo o `false` si presionó el botón negativo.

**UPDATE**

Luego que agregaste el comentario de que deseas recibir el texto ingresado, he modificado el método:

```dart
Future<T?> showMyDialog<T>({
  required BuildContext context,
  required String title,
  required InputDecoration decoration,
  bool barrierDismissible = true,
  Color? barrierColor,
}) {
  final textController = TextEditingController();
  return showDialog(
      barrierDismissible: barrierDismissible,
      context: context,
      builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
            title: Text(title),
            content: TextField(
              decoration: decoration,
              controller: textController,
            ),
            actions: [
              ElevatedButton(
                child: const Text('Aceptar'),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).pop(textController.text);
                },
              ),
              ElevatedButton(
                child: const Text('Cancelar'),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                },
              )
            ],
          ));
}
```

Lo llamarías así:

```dart
  final result = await showMyDialog(
    context: context,
    title: 'Titulo',
    decoration: const InputDecoration(
      hintText: 'Tu texto hint',
    ),
  );

  print('result: $result');
```

También podrías extraer todo ese `AlertDialog` y meterlo dentro de un `StatefulWidget` por si deseas manejar más cosas.

Comment: Muchas gracias Diego, soy seguidor tuyo en youtuve, y he aprendido mucho de vos. Pero lo que tengo que devolver es el texto ingresado en el TextField

Comment: ahí acabo de actualizar mi respuesta